# How to convert the value of textfile into a specific list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I just dont know how to interpret what I wanted to do, but I will state otherwise. I have a input.txt which holds these list of words separated by 1 blank line:

```
your
name
is

kimi
no
nawa
```

Now i wanted them to be stored in a lists or string with similar results like:

```
list = ['your','name','is','kim','no','nawa']
```

or

```
string = 'yournameiskiminonawa
```

or

```
list1 = ['your','name','is']
list2 = ['kim','no','nawa']

string = 'kiminonawa'
string1 = 'yournameis'
```

and below is my startup code:

```
values = []
    for line in open('input.txt'):
    line = line.split()
    for value in line:
        values.append(value)
    print line
```

Comment: Which of the four possible outputs that you list do you actually want?

Comment: Also, does your file deliberately have that extra empty line? You are also really complicating this. Keep only `for line open('input.txt')` and print `line` only to see what is happening in the first loop. Remove that extra inner loop. Look at what you have, and you will realize what your mistake is

Comment: All of them. I'm experimenting right now, so it would be best to take them all and teach me the proper way..

Comment: I agree with @Tagc. Which output do you want?

Comment: @idjaw yes it does have, and I'm really new to python.

Answer (score 1):

Here are implementations of functions that give you outputs in the four ways you specify. They operate on string data, which you can access by opening the file with `open('input.txt').read()`.

```
DATA = """
your
name
is

kimi
no
nawa"""

def as_one_list(s):
    return [x for x in s.splitlines() if x]

def as_one_string(s):
    return ''.join(as_one_list(s))

def as_two_lists(s):
    return tuple(as_one_list(x) for x in s.split('\n\n')[:2])

def as_two_strings(s):
    return tuple(as_one_string(x) for x in s.split('\n\n')[:2])

print(as_one_list(DATA))
print(as_one_string(DATA))
print(as_two_lists(DATA))
print(as_two_strings(DATA))
```

**Output**

```
['your', 'name', 'is', 'kimi', 'no', 'nawa']
yournameiskiminonawa
(['your', 'name', 'is'], ['kimi', 'no', 'nawa'])
('yournameis', 'kiminonawa')
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you really want?

```
l=[i for i in open('input.txt') if len(i.strip()]
```

Here is an example

Comment: I would like to know the 4 as much as possible.

Comment: You're missing a paranthesis near the end.